# Can't modify Managed Properties in SP2019 Search Service that was migrated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, migration

I'm having an issue with editing Managed Properties in a Search Service I migrated from SP2013 to SP2019, yes I bounced it through SP2016, with the DB attach method.  I've run a full crawl in SP2019 but when I try to edit a managed property from Central Admin I get this error when I try to save the changes.

> The settings could not be saved because of an internal error: Search
>   has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned.
>   If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.

This is not a permissions issue, I've tried with several different accounts including the farm account and the installer account.  I checked and I am able to edit the properties in SP2013, and in the SP2016 farm that i'm bouncing through.

LOGS:

```
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:http://ccspapp01:2019/_admin/search/managedproperty.aspx?property=15Day-0OWSCHCS&appid={139d70c6-c1a9-487a-84ee-3d7884ced6a6})   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwhz   Medium  SPRequestModule.BeginRequestHandler End, SP Build Version: '16.0.10348.12104'   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh6   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler Begin    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime b6x53   Medium  PerformanceInspector does not exist.    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime ajd6k   Medium  Value for isAnonymousAllowed is : False 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.68  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime ajd6l   Medium  Value for checkAuthenticationCookie is : True   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (PostAuthenticateRequestHandler) Execution Time=6.9868; CPU Milliseconds=3; SQL Query Count=1; Parent=Request (POST:http://ccspapp01:2019/_admin/search/managedproperty.aspx?property=15Day-0OWSCHCS&appid={139d70c6-c1a9-487a-84ee-3d7884ced6a6}) 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh7   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler End  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh8   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostAuthorizeRequestHandler Begin   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh0   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler Begin    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh1   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler End  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime aj1kn   Medium  SPRequestModule.AcquireRequestStateHandler  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh2   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostAcquireRequestStateHandler Begin    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwh3   Medium  SPRequestModule.PostAcquireRequestStateHandler End  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwhu   Medium  SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler Begin   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.69  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Asp Runtime avwhv   Medium  SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler End 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Experiment Manager: GetExpName user: "MY USER NAME" 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Experiment Manager: GetExpName cookie: unknown  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Experiment Manager: GetExpName tenant: ccspapp01:2019   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Experiment Manager: GetExpName final key:   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Experiment Manager: GetExpName expName: production  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Component Manager: public CreateInstance: Microsoft.SharePoint.Context.ContextInfo  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   CSOM    bhxdp   Medium  Component Manager: Look in production   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   General bj421   Medium  TryGetGridInformation from SPFarm.Local Start: My Scenario Start    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   General bj422   Medium  TryGetGridInformation from SPFarm.Local Success: My Scenario Success    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.70  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   General a4hvw   Medium  VdbNavStruct::LoadScopeMap - Failed to insert ScopeId:{FDB0F1A4-D2C2-4F9B-9C5E-BBF0458762A5}  into the scope map.   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Config DB   a99o1   Medium  Cloning object 139d70c6-c1a9-487a-84ee-3d7884ced6a6 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    a0ic2   Medium  Refreshed SPPersistedObject with Name Search Service Application, Id 139d70c6-c1a9-487a-84ee-3d7884ced6a6, Parent 61f69a56-ae02-49e0-a21f-b3bbb77a2c06, Version 273884. Last update info: [User: COVEREDCA\SPFarm Process:OWSTIMER (11448) Machine:CCSPAPP10 Time:July 24, 2019 14:15:08.0000 Stack trace (Thread [19] CorrelationId [3480f39e-67f7-104c-2f38-7b81f96071fd]): ] 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   b5k6g   Medium  SSAProxy call without SubscriptionId: [GetManagedProperty]  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   b5k6h   Medium     at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)     at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.LogInvocationSubscription(String operationName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Boolean asService, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetManagedProperty(String managedPropertyName, SearchObjectOwner owner)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.ManagedPropertyPageHelper.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.CentralAdmin.ManagedPropertyPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   ana95   Medium  SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetManagedProperty--timeouts=120000,120000   1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetManagedProperty--Proxy Name:Search Service Proxy EndPoint: http://ccspapp04:32843/139d70c6c1a9487a84ee3d7884ced6a6/SearchService.svc  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk8z    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 1.0005    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   bm83r   Medium  SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetManagedProperty - Open Elapsed Time: 1 Endpoint: http://ccspapp04:32843/139d70c6c1a9487a84ee3d7884ced6a6/SearchService.svc    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.71  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://ccspapp04:32843/139d70c6c1a9487a84ee3d7884ced6a6/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISchemaOperations/GetManagedProperty' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:88734fd9-e7f5-4924-9b48-50ded8ab2948'  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.79  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   General bojl7   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/25/2019 14:06:23.71, Original Level: VerboseEx] SPMonitoredScope {0} dispose is completing  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.79  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Usage Infrastructure    brsbw   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Usage Event {0} of type {1} is disabled for CIL  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.79  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://tempuri.org/ISchemaOperations/GetManagedProperty) Execution Time=79.4216; CPU Milliseconds=2; SQL Query Count=6; Parent=GetManagedProperty 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.79  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (GetManagedProperty) Execution Time=80.378; CPU Milliseconds=3; SQL Query Count=6; Parent=Request (POST:http://ccspapp01:2019/_admin/search/managedproperty.aspx?property=15Day-0OWSCHCS&appid={139d70c6-c1a9-487a-84ee-3d7884ced6a6}) 1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.79  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka2    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetManagedProperty--Id: Elapsed Time: 81 Proxy Name/ID: Search Service Proxy/835a8054-fed7-4a33-93f1-30c1c6e72705 EndPoint: http://ccspapp04:32843/139d70c6c1a9487a84ee3d7884ced6a6/SearchService.svc    1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.79  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   b5k6g   Medium  SSAProxy call without SubscriptionId: [SetManagedPropertyMappings]  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
07/25/2019 14:06:23.80  w3wp.exe (0x1490)   0x0F4C  SharePoint Server Search    Query   b5k6h   Medium     at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)     at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.LogInvocationSubscription(String operationName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Boolean asService, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.SetManagedPropertyMappings(ManagedPropertyInfo managedProperty, IEnumerable`1 mappingCollection, SearchObjectOwner owner)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.ManagedPropertyPageHelper.OkButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  1ad2f39e-77b4-104c-0a10-18076a319aca
```

Comment: Please grab the error logs for the correlation ID associated with the error and add them to your question.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorSeward I've added the logs that I think apply.  I'm not getting a correlation ID so this is a best effort.  Also clearing the config cache and re-creating the Search Proxy did nothing.

Comment: Are these your custom managed properties you've migrated or default ones coming with SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, another admin had installed a custom claims provider "AzureCP" as part of another task to integrate authentication with AzureAD.  This solution has be installed to the GAC on each server in the farm, not just the WFEs.  This broke the STS service on the non-WFE boxes and was causing this error.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Central Administration->Manage service applications->Search service application->Content sources->edit relevant content source, check the URLs are correct in Start Addresses box.

Click “Index Reset” in the left navigation to reset index, then start a full crawl and check if the issue exists after completing.